# How to view actual header values sent after a request?

Tags: rest, rest-client

How do you see the actual headers that was sent in a request after you send out a request in Rest Client? I can see the response completely, but it does not show the actual headers that were sent out. I could not see them in any of the output windows in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

> Every time you send an http request, the request details, including method, url, headers, and body, are saved into a file for future reference. To access this content, you can use the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+H(Cmd+Alt+H for macOS), or press F1 and then select/type Rest Client: Request History. This will allow you to view the last 50 request items in time reversing order, displaying the method, url, and request time for each one. After specified request history item is selected, the request details would be displayed in a temp file, you can view the request details or follow previous step to trigger the request again.
> *src:*  https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient#request-history

[image]

[image]

```http
GET https://google.com
User-Agent: vscode-restclient
accept: application/json
```